# Apache Jena - not getting the desired result

Tags: jena

I'm adding few resources and properties in a Model like this:

```
String xyz = "http://www.example.com/xyz";
   String creator = "http://www.example.com/Harry";
   String email = "http://www.example.com/harry@xyz.com";
   Resource creat = m.createResource(creator);
   Resource eId = m.createResource(email);
   Resource res =        m.createResource(xyz).addProperty(DC.creator,creat.addProperty(VCARD.EMAIL, eId));
   m.write(System.out);
```

I'm getting this as a result:

```
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:vcard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" > 
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/xyz">
<dc:creator rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/Harry"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/Harry">
<vcard:EMAIL rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/harry@xyz.com"/>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Is there any other way by which I can get the result Like:

```
<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:vcard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" > 
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.example.com/xyz">
<dc:creator rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/Harry"/>
    <vcard:EMAIL rdf:resource="http://www.example.com/harry@xyz.com"/>
</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the RDF/XML pretty writer: Use

```
model.write( .... , "RDF/XML_ABBREV")
```

or use Turtle.